# Dispatching same job from handle function always stops after timeout

Tags: php, laravel, queue, beanstalkd, laravel-queue

I've been working on making an excel export functionality for my application. Due to large number of rows, and large number of columns, and the timeout value being 5 minutes, I split the payload of the job into multiple of the same job with different parameters, then just append the new rows to the existing Excel file.

I am getting the following error:

```
        [2019-07-08 14:13:04] local.ERROR: Test\Jobs\CalculateExport has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Queue\\MaxAttemptsExceededException(code: 0): Test\\Jobs\\CalculateExport has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:394)
    [stacktrace]
    #0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(314): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->markJobAsFailedIfAlreadyExceedsMaxAttempts('beanstalkd', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\BeanstalkdJob), 1)
    #1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(270): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->process('beanstalkd', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\BeanstalkdJob), Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
    #2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(227): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\BeanstalkdJob), 'beanstalkd', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
    #3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runNextJob('beanstalkd', 'default', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
    #4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(85): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('beanstalkd', 'default')
    #5 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
    #6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
    #8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
    #9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(549): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
    #10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
    #11 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
    #12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
    #13 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(960): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #14 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(255): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Ob

ject(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(88): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(121): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /var/www/html/artisan(35): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#19 {main}
"}
```

Beanstalkd is used as the queue processor. No exceptions seem to be happening aside from the one above.

The job class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Jobs;

use Log;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use PanelApi\v2\Export;

class CalculateExport implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $export;

    private $params;

    public $tries = 1;
    public $timeout = 0;

    /**
     * CalculateExport constructor.
     * @param Export $export
     * @param null $params
     */
    public function __construct(Export $export, $params = null)
    {
        $this->export = $export;
        $this->params = $params;
        Log::info($this->params);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        if (empty($this->params)) {
            $this->export->calculateExport();
            $this->delete();
        } else {
            $skip = isset($this->params['skip']) ? $this->params['skip'] : 0;
            $excelFilePath = isset($this->params['excelFilePath']) ? $this->params['excelFilePath'] : null;
            $totalCount = isset($this->params['totalCount']) ? $this->params['totalCount'] : null;
            $this->export->calculateExport($skip, $excelFilePath, $totalCount);
            $this->delete();
        }

    }
}
```

The calculate export method like this:

```
public function calculateExport($skip = 0, $excelFilePath = null, $totalCount = null)
    {
        try {

            // FIXME: investigate this more
            ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
            set_time_limit(0);

            $this->load('hard_filters_condition', 'test', 'exportAttributes');

            $test_id = $this->test->id;
            $p = \Test\v2\Test::where('test_id', $test_id);

            $testColumns = collect($this->exportAttributes)
                ->filter(function ($item) {
                    return $item['attribute_type'] == 'metadata';
                })
                ->map(function ($item) {
                    return $item['attribute_code'];
                })
                ->toArray();
            array_unshift($testColumns, 'email');
            array_unshift($testColumns, 'id');
            $questionColumnIds = collect($this->exportAttributes)
                ->filter(function ($item) {
                    return $item['attribute_type'] == 'question';
                })
                ->map(function ($item) {
                    return explode('_', $item['attribute_code'])[1];
                })
                ->toArray();

            $hard_filter = $this->hard_filters_condition;
            if ($hard_filter) {
                $p = $p->where(function ($query) use ($hard_filter) {
                    $query = $hard_filter->getInvitationQuery($query);
                });
            }

            // get the actual questions by ids
            $questions = Question::whereIn('id', $questionColumnIds)->get();

            $textQuestionIds = implode(',', $questions
                ->filter(function ($question) {
                    return $question->type == 'text';
                })
                ->map(function ($question) {
                    return $question->id;
                })
                ->toArray());
            $nonTextQuestionIds = implode(',', $questions
                ->filter(function ($question) {
                    return $question->type != 'text';
                })
                ->map(function ($question) {
                    return $question->id;
                })
                ->toArray());

            // test select columns
            $testColumnsToSelect = collect($testColumns)
                ->map(function ($item) {
                    return "tests.$item";
                })
                ->toArray();

            $testCount = empty($totalCount) ? $p->count() : $totalCount;
            $LIMIT = 50;

            $p = $p->select($testColumnsToSelect)
                ->skip($skip)
                ->take($LIMIT);

            $testCursor = $p->cursor();

            if (empty($totalCount)) {
                $this->hard_filtered_count = $testCount;
                $this->hard_filtered_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
                $this->save();
                Log::info('HARD FILTERED COUNT:' . $testCount);
            }

            $PROGRESS_FACTOR = 0.01;
            $progressIncrement = round($testCount * $PROGRESS_FACTOR);

            $fileName = "";

            if (empty($excelFilePath)) {
                $bytes = random_bytes(32);
                $randomId = bin2hex($bytes);
                // 1. Init Excel file
                $date = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
                $fileName = "Test_export_{$this->id}_" . $randomId . "_$date";
            } else {
                $fileName = $excelFilePath;
            }

            $excelHeaders = array_merge($testColumns, collect($questions)
                ->map(function ($item) {
                    return $item->code;
                })
                ->toArray());

            if (empty($excelFilePath)) {
                $counter = $skip;
                Log::info('Starting first job for excel file: ' . $excelFilePath . ' with test count: ' . $testCount . ' and questions count ' . $questions->count());
                Excel::create($fileName, function ($excel) use ($testCursor, $questions, $progressIncrement, $testCount, $excelHeaders, $skip, &$counter, $nonTextQuestionIds, $textQuestionIds) {

                    $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function ($sheet) use ($testCursor, $questions, $progressIncrement, $testCount, $excelHeaders, $skip, &$counter, $nonTextQuestionIds, $textQuestionIds) {

                        $sheet->prependRow($excelHeaders);
                        $sheet->row(1, function ($row) {
                            $row->setFontWeight('bold');
                        });
                        $sheet->freezeFirstRow();

                        foreach ($testCursor as $test) {
                            $row = $test->toArray();
                            // get answers to all questions for that user
                            Log::info('First job - iteration ' . ($counter + 1));
                            $nonTextAnswers = collect(DB::select(DB::raw("
                            SELECT pa.question_id, qo.name
                            FROM   test_answers pa, question_options qo
                            WHERE  pa.test_id = :test_id
                            AND    pa.question_id IN ($nonTextQuestionIds)
                            AND    qo.id = pa.choice_option_id;
                        "), ['test_id' => $test->id]));
                            $textAnswers = collect(DB::select(DB::raw("
                            SELECT pa.question_id, pa.text
                            FROM   test_answers pa
                            WHERE  pa.test_id = :test_id
                            AND    pa.question_id IN ($textQuestionIds);
                        "), ['test_id' => $test->id]));
                            Log::info('First job - iteration ' . ($counter + 1) . ' gotten test answers');
                            foreach ($questions as $question) {

                                if ($question->type != 'text') {

                                    $answers = $nonTextAnswers
                                        ->filter(function ($item) use ($question) {
                                            return $item->question_id == $question->id;
                                        })
                                        ->map(function ($item) {
                                            return $item->name;
                                        })
                                        ->toArray();
                                    $answer = implode(', ', $answers);
                                    $row[$question->code] = $answer;
                                } else {
                                    $answer = array_values($textAnswers
                                        ->filter(function ($item) use ($question) {
                                            return $item->question_id == $question->id;
                                        })
                                        ->toArray());
                                    if (count($answer) > 0) {
                                        $row[$question->code] = $answer[0]->text;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            $excelRow = [];
                            foreach ($excelHeaders as $header) {
                                array_push($excelRow, isset($row[$header]) ? $row[$header] : "");
                            }
                            Log::info('First job - iteration ' . ($counter + 1) . ' appending excel row');
                            $sheet->appendRow($excelRow);
                            $counter++;
                        }
                        $this->calculated_percent = round($counter / $testCount * 100, 2);
                        Log::info('First job - iteration ' . ($counter + 1) . ' updating export row in db');
                        $this->save();
                    });

                })->store('xlsx');
                if ($counter < $testCount) {
                    // dispatch next job
                    Log::info("Processed $counter tests, starting next job");
                    dispatch(new CalculateExport($this, [
                        'skip' => $counter,
                        'totalCount' => $testCount,
                        'excelFilePath' => $fileName
                    ]));
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                $counter = $skip;
                Excel::load(storage_path('exports') . $ds . $fileName . '.xlsx', function ($reader) use ($testCursor, $questions, $excelHeaders, $progressIncrement, $testCount, &$counter, $nonTextQuestionIds, $textQuestionIds) {
                    $reader->sheet('Sheet 1', function ($sheet) use ($testCursor, $questions, $excelHeaders, $progressIncrement, $testCount, &$counter, $nonTextQuestionIds, $textQuestionIds) {

                        foreach ($testCursor as $test) {
                            $row = $test->toArray();
                            // get answers to all questions for that user
                            Log::info('Update job - iteration ' . ($counter + 1));
                            $nonTextAnswers = collect(DB::select(DB::raw("
                            SELECT pa.question_id, qo.name
                            FROM   test_answers pa, question_options qo
                            WHERE  pa.test_id = :test_id
                            AND    pa.question_id IN ($nonTextQuestionIds)
                            AND    qo.id = pa.choice_option_id;
                        "), ['test_id' => $test->id]));
                            $textAnswers = collect(DB::select(DB::raw("
                            SELECT pa.question_id, pa.text
                            FROM   test_answers pa
                            WHERE  pa.ptest_id = :test_id
                            AND    pa.question_id IN ($textQuestionIds);
                        "), ['test_id' => $test->id]));
                            Log::info('Update job - iteration ' . ($counter + 1) . ' gotten answers');
                            foreach ($questions as $question) {

                                if ($question->type != 'text') {

                                    $answers = $nonTextAnswers
                                        ->filter(function ($item) use ($question) {
                                            return $item->question_id == $question->id;
                                        })
                                        ->map(function ($item) {
                                            return $item->name;
                                        })
                                        ->toArray();
                                    $answer = implode(', ', $answers);
                                    $row[$question->code] = $answer;
                                } else {
                                    $answer = array_values($textAnswers
                                        ->filter(function ($item) use ($question) {
                                            return $item->question_id == $question->id;
                                        })
                                        ->toArray());
                                    if (count($answer) > 0) {
                                        $row[$question->code] = $answer[0]->text;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            $excelRow = [];
                            foreach ($excelHeaders as $header) {
                                array_push($excelRow, isset($row[$header]) ? $row[$header] : "");
                            }
                            Log::info('Update job - iteration ' . ($counter + 1) . ' appending excel row');
                            $sheet->appendRow($excelRow);
                            $counter++;
                        }
                        $this->calculated_percent = round($counter / $testCount * 100, 2);
                        Log::info('Update job - iteration ' . ($counter + 1) . ' update export row in db');
                        $this->save();
                    });
                })->store('xlsx');
                if ($counter < $testCount) {
                    // dispatch next job
                    Log::info("Processed $counter tests, starting next job");
                    CalculateExport::dispatch($this, [
                        'skip' => $counter,
                        'totalCount' => $testCount,
                        'excelFilePath' => $fileName
                    ]);
                    dispatch(new CalculateExport($this, [
                        'skip' => $counter,
                        'totalCount' => $testCount,
                        'excelFilePath' => $fileName
                    ]));
                    return;
                }
            }
            Log::info("Processing Excel finished, uploading to s3");
            // upload to S3
            $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            $diskPath = storage_path('exports') . $ds . $fileName . '.xlsx';
            $contents = file_get_contents($diskPath);
            Storage::disk('s3_circle_public')->put($fileName . '.xlsx', $contents);
            $path = Storage::disk('s3_circle_public')->url($fileName . '.xlsx');
            $this->export_url = $path;
            $this->save();

            // update percent
            $this->calculated_percent = 100;
            $this->calculated_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
            $this->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
            Log::error($e->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }
```

I've tried changing the job timeout on the job itself, changing the CalculateExport::dispatch with global dispatch, setting tries to one. I see in beastalkd console that jobs get dispatched one after another. But as soon as 5 minutes is reached, it ends. What I am suspecting is that it somehow never finished the previous job - that is why I added the delete job.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the calculateExport function set also the PHP parameter max_execution_time.

ini_set('max_execution_time', 2000);

Probably now is set to now to 300 (seconds) = 5 minutes

Comment: The whole export process will occasionally run more than for example 2000 seconds. Can the time be set to infinite? Any idea about whether I am dispatching the same job with different parameters correctly?